# US Date Format in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to use `Date.ToShortDateString()` but make it spit out the date in US format. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this for an ASP.NET app, or something else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Console.WriteLine(dateToDisplay.ToShortDateString());
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(dateToDisplay.ToString("d", new CultureInfo("en-US")));
```